# How to initialise a model and call a custom function within the class

Tags: angular

I have a user service where i get a object from my mongo db. The user object contains a dob which i want to convert to an age in angular.

I created a custom user class to do this declaring a getAge function. However when calling this user.getAge() function it says

> "this.user.getAge() is not a function"

user.model.ts

```
export class User {

  user: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  getAge() {

return "Age"

  }
}
```

profile.component.ts

```
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {User} from '../../models/user.model'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    user: User;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.route.params.switchMap((params) => {
            let user_id = params['id'];
            return this.userService.get(user_id);
        }).subscribe((res) => {
            this.user = res;
            let age = this.user.getAge();
            console.log(age);

        });
    }

}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {


    path = 'users/';

    constructor(
        private apiService: ApiService
    ) {

    }

    all() {
        return this.apiService.get(this.path);
    }

    create(user) {

        return this.apiService.post(this.path, user);

    }

    get(user_id) {

        let endpoint = this.path + user_id;

        return this.apiService.get(endpoint);
    }

}
```

user.model.js

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({

        email: {
            address: {
                type: String,
                lowercase: true,
                //unique: true,

            },
            token: String,
            verified: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
        },

        socketId: String,
        isOnline: Boolean,

        phone: {
            countryCode: {
                type: String,
            },
            number: {
                type: String,
            },
            code: String,
            verified: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
        },

        jwt: String,

        profile: {
            username: String,
            firstname: String,
            lastname: String,
            dob: String,
            gender: String,
            level: Number,
            location: {
                longitude: String,
                latitude: String
            },
            image: String,
            introduction: String,

            following: [],
            followers: [],

        },

    },
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}
    });
```

Comment: what are you trying to return in the get age as you are already setting it to a user, can you show how your user model looks like

Comment: I provided the model, its quite large thats why its not possible to create all the properties in my angular user class. To clarify i have a dob and i want to convert to an age. I need to manipulate so other things aswell not just dob but thats later on.

Answer (score 3):

`UserService.get()` returns `any` so typescript allows you to assign it to `ProfileComponent.user` (type `User`). `new User()` is never call so 
a `User` object never exits `UserService.get()` really returns `Observable<Object>` with all of the properties in your model. What you need is:

```
public get(user_id): Observable<User> {
    let endpoint = this.path + user_id;
    return this.apiService.get(endpoint).map(res => {
        let userObj = new User();
        userObj.user = res;
        return userObj;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the result to a new user object with object assignment. like below

```js
this.route.params.switchMap((params) => {
    let user_id = params['id'];
    return this.userService.get(user_id);
}).subscribe((res) => {

    let userRef: User = new User();
    Object.assign(userRef, res);

    this.user = userRef;
    let age = this.user.getAge();
    console.log(age);

});
```

Or you can do this from the `user.model.ts`

```js
export class User {
  user: any;
  constructor() {}
  getAge(){ return "Age"}
  public static fromObject(obj):User { 
    let userRef: User = new User();
    Object.assign(userRef, obj);
    return userRef;
  }
}
```

and in your component or service you can do this by importing the User model

```js
this.route.params.switchMap((params) => {
    let user_id = params['id'];
    return this.userService.get(user_id);
}).subscribe((res) => {
    this.user = User.fromObject(res);
    let age = this.user.getAge();
    console.log(age);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    get(user_id) {

       let endpoint = this.path + user_id;

       return this.apiService.get(endpoint).map(res => new User(){//set your user properties here});
   }
```